Win 11 PC loses ability to ping windows server on local network randomly
I am at my wits end here. I have PC A, a Win 11 pro machine, and PC B, a Windows Server 2019 machine on the same local network. For over a year I have been able to remote into B from A without issue, but now, run into issues pinging and connecting to PC B.
Starting this week, while in a middle of a RDP connection with PC-B, I will get disconnected and receive a message that the local device could not be found on the network. I will attempt to reconnect, and get the same message. I attempt to ping the local IP address of PC B, and get no response. For a period of time, switching the ethernet connection on my PC to my other Ethernet jack would allow the connection to ping and RDP again, only for it to happen again after 2 hours. Now switching the jacks does not work anymore. When manually going to PC B, I can ping PC A without issue, however A-B will result in a timeout.
Somethings I have verified and tried:

Verified both machines are on same subnet and have same gateway
Gave both device static IP addresses to make sure DHCP not issue (PC B has already been static since initialization)
Verified both devices have unique IP's on local network
Disabled Windows Defender firewall, and uninstalled glasswire from PC-A
Disabled VPN software, drivers, and network devices on PC A
Flushing DNS

Please let me know your thoughts. There have been no updates to the network stack recently, and this just started this week. Is there any way I can use something like packet tracer to identify where specifically it is being blocked? What could possibly be doing this in the middle of an active connection? If it was a misconfiguration, I assume it just wouldn't work wholesale, not initially and then stop.

When PC A stops being able to ping the server, can it still do other network-related operations (e.g., access the internet)

Yes, all other operations seem to be unaffected, can access internet, and even other local servers from PC A, just not PC B. PC B also has internet capabilities when the "outage" happens.
